# My Ec2 instance showing unable to connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have one micro ec2 instance in AWS in which i am having one of my sqlite databases.everything is working fine for me till yesterday,i have configured security groups to allow all incoming trafics to port 80,and ssh.But from yesterday i was not able to connect to my instance through browser.it is showing unable to connect.But i have been able to scp in to it and ssh in to it.And the console showing the server instance is running perfectly.Can anybody help me to sort out this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will solve your any problems related to ec2 instances 
I changed the instance type and reboot it,then reassociate the public IP.My problem is solved
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html

Answer (score 0):

Could provide more details:

1. From the browser are you accessing any application and how ec-ip/appname ?
2. After you ssh to the server can you access the same using command line browser..if machine is linux try `elinks "http:// localhost/appname.."`

Comment: NOw i am not able to do anything on to it.network error is shown by both scp ,ssh

Comment: can u give any hint abt the reasons.the console is showing my server is running perfectly and now i changed its type to small can u reply me/

Comment: There can me couple of reasons. Just quoting it down.. 1) The private key has changed or you used different one or generated new one. 2) If you have changed the permissions to .ssh folder to 777 in linux. Could you paste the log message after ssh -v user@address. So that I can know what the error is.